# PayPal Price Customization

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I am planning on using the PayPal SDK for people to donate in the app, but I want the user to enter how much money they want to give rather than having just a predefined button with a specific amount, like shown in the SDK exmaple, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

> 1. Tools
> 2. PayPal Buttons
> 3. Create a Button
> 4. Select donation from the dropdown menu

[image]

Then you will need to take that embedded code and paste it in the source code of your website.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I am trying to implement the PayPal iOS SDK, not for a website.

Comment: Oh, why didn't you say so. Here's the link: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK
Please mark this post as solved and upvote. Thanks and good luck on your project.